# Changing file permissions of a file Linux assembly (NASM assembler)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, octal

I'm having trouble with changing permissions of a file using syscal call function number 15 (that is sys_chmod). Here is my code snippet:

```
mov eax, 15
mov ebx, fileName
mov ecx, 00400 | 00200 | 00040
int 80h
```

where 00400 & 00200=read and write by owner and 00040 read my group obviously.

The thing is that the file is not set properly. It sets correct for owner, but for group it doesn't set read, but write instead. Then I tried to use only 00400 | 00200, and strange thing happened, the owner was set OK, but the group was set to write also.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention what assembler you are using. Make sure it interprets those numbers in octal. [nasm, for example, doesn't](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.1) and will produce the result you see.

A small quote from the linked manual:

```
mov     ax,200          ; decimal 
mov     ax,0200         ; still decimal 
mov     ax,0200d        ; explicitly decimal 
mov     ax,0d200        ; also decimal 
mov     ax,0c8h         ; hex 
mov     ax,$0c8         ; hex again: the 0 is required 
mov     ax,0xc8         ; hex yet again 
mov     ax,0hc8         ; still hex 
mov     ax,310q         ; octal 
mov     ax,310o         ; octal again 
mov     ax,0o310        ; octal yet again 
mov     ax,0q310        ; octal yet again
```

Comment: I am using nasm yes. I'll look that up then. Or do you already know the answer maybe?